# How to install tribar theme for plymouth?

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

I miss tribar theme from RHEL/Debian. I cannot find it for Ubuntu.
Do you have any idea why there is no tribar? How to set it? Do you know any other so simple and cute text theme, that is available in Ubuntu?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you find it for debian? It will work on Ubuntu also, it is a Plymouth theme not an Ubuntu theme, OS should not matter.

Comment: compare:
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/plymouth/filelist and http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/plymouth/filelist
You will see that Ubuntu doesn't have 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/tribar.so file.
Unfortunately it's not so ease to copy that file, I think.

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo apt purge plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
2. sudo apt install plymouth-themes
3. sudo update-alternatives --install '/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth' default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/tribar/tribar.plymouth 100
4. sudo update-initramfs -u
5. reboot